# pass the current path as argument in a meteor template

Tags: meteor

How can I pass the current path in a meteor template as in

```
{{> sometemplate somearg="{{currentpath}}" }}
```

Where current path is basically what would be returned by `window.location.pathname`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple helper for this:

```
Template.parentTemplate.helpers({
  currentPath: function() {
    return window.location.pathname;
  }
});
```

And call it in your template using:

```
<template name="parentTemplate>
  {{!-- ... --}}
  {{> sometemplate somearg=currentPath }}
</template>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working. If I make it print the pathname to the console I think the issue is that meteor updates the location sometime after the helper is run so it's got the wrong pathname at the time function is executed.